# Cannot locate webpage element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate the "creat your Amazon account" button in this page:
[log in page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7gWq.png)

I tried a lot of codes to locate and click the button, the error is always "NoSuchElementExcepetion, Unable to locate element"

```
find_element_by_xpath("//*[id='createAccountSubmit']")

find_element_by_xpath("//*[id='auth-create-account-link']")

find_element_by_xpath("//*[tabindex='6']")

find_element_by_xpath("//*[class='a-button-inner']")

find_element_by_xpath("//*[class='a-button-text']")

find_element_by_xpath("//*[class='a-button-text']")
```

How can I locate and click the button.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using XPath, even more for elements that have ID in the form.
You should easily find the element using these selectors:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='createAccountSubmit']")
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_id("createAccountSubmit")
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#createAccountSubmit")
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.a-button-text")
```

You can check [this link](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) for different ways to get elements on the page.
I would recomend to use CSS selectors when you can, instead of XPath.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, these codes does not work, it seems the webpage is divided by a particular way.